# How to store multiple utf8 symbols (uint32_ts) from utfcpp as a string?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using the `utfcpp` lib, one could split a string (`'哈哈哈'`) encoded in `utf8` into several `uint32_t`s (or symbols`(21704, 21704, 21704)`) which act like `char`s for `std::string`.

In this situation, what's the best solution store the `uint32_t` ('character') sequences (as a 'string')?

For example, putting `(21704, 21704, 21704)` into a `vector<uint32_t>` will require iterating the vector for 'string comparison', which seems [slower](http://quick-bench.com/l81nLj4FGP1_8TQzc0Jz_ZfK6HA) than the real version of `std::string`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `std::wstring` or your own brew [`std::basic_string<uint32_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

This would let you use their operators and functions to manipulate such objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've thought that only `char` and `wchar_t` are supposed to used in `std::basic_string`. I tried to output a `std::basic_string<uint32_t>` string using `std::basic_ostream<uint32_t> os;`, but the compiler told me that it's a protected constructor. How can I output this `std::basic_string<uint32_t>` string?

Comment: @Edityouprofile Your question was about storing such strings, not about outputting them. For output, you'd need to convert it back to something you know how to output -- the same way you'd need to perform a conversion if you'd stick with `vector<uint32_t>`.

Comment: About this answer: I wouldn't recommend `std::wstring`. `wchar_t` may be too small to hold all Unicode code points.

Comment: @Edityouprofile hvd is right about `wchar_t`. Check if it suits you before using it.

Comment: @hvd the last time I checked `wchar_t` documentation, it was something like _"large enough to hold **any** supported character code point"_ and then something about 32 vs. 64 bits systems ... IIRC. What does _supported_ mean?

Comment: @YSC Mean to be a unicode codepoint everywhere unicode is supported, so 32 bits (when unicode is not supported could be literally anything as long as it's not smaller that `char`), except windows which uses `wchar_t` as units for their "approximately UTF-16" strings. In other words, not suitable for any purpose if you're trying to stay cross platform.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details. Adding the `std::basic_string<uint32_t>` and other version of `string`s, all of them seems still [slower(link)](http://quick-bench.com/xVwYp1JWDxznEfM6q5Ip6DVdxDE) than the `char` and `wchar_t` version. Is the compiler optimize these two by default?

Comment: It means *any Unicode character supported by the platform*. That means the full Unicode charset if `wchar_t` is 32 bits large, or only the Base Multilingual Plane when it is only 16 bits large. Said differently it is implementation dependant...

Comment: @YSC `wchar_t` is large enough to hold any member of the extended execution character set (that's C wording, C++ speaks of "execution wide-character set" instead), but the extended execution character set is not required to be Unicode.

Comment: I should have asked a proper question, you deserve rep for that guys. Thx

Comment: @Edityouprofile: do not use `std::basic_string<uint32_t>` when specializations for `std::basic_string<char32_t>` exist in the standard library.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hi, I've just read your answer. I tried this because `utf8::next` returns a `uint32_t`. After referencing to Cpprefference, it tells me that `char32_t` is a typedef of `uint_least32_t` which offers *at least* 32 bits, while `uint32_t` offers *exactly* 32 bits. So I think it is safe to put this `uint32_t` into a `std::basic_string<char32_t>`.

Comment: @Edityouprofile: the safest way IMHO is to cast the return value of `utf8::next` to a `char32_t` and only use char like types to hold characters...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hi, you're right. I [tried(link)](http://quick-bench.com/6JseSQn4fe8ijLZFL5GJGy34ibQ) `u32string` and the `char` and `wchar_t` string comparison are still the fastest. Is it deal to optimization from complier or less number of bits? But the time does not seem to be linearly grow with the number of bits...

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of C++ come with `char16_t` and `char32_t`. They should be prefered to `uintxx_t` types because clause 24.2 Character traits [char.traits] mandates the definition of specialization of `char_traits` for it:

> This subclause defines requirements on classes representing character traits, and defines a class template
>   `char_traits<charT>`, along with four specializations, `char_traits<char>`, `char_traits<char16_t>`,
>   `char_traits<char32_t>`, and `char_traits<wchar_t>`, that satisfy those requirements.

This even allows immediate access to a `basic_string` specialization: 24.3 String classes [string.classes] says

> The header `<string>` defines the basic_string class template for manipulating varying-length sequences
>   of char-like objects and four typedef-names, `string`, `u16string`, `u32string`, and `wstring`, that name the
>   specializations `basic_string<char>`, `basic_string<char16_t>`, `basic_string<char32_t>`, and `basic_string<wchar_t>`, respectively.

Unfortunately, when it comes to direct io no such specializations exists out of the box for `basic_stream<char32_t>`, but UTF8 locales should have converters between `char32_t` and `char`.